# Css before and after content blocking text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design a octagon with texts stuffed inside. But somehow the text is not showing. Please help!

**HTML**

```
<div class = "octagon">This is some text</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.octagon 
{ 
    width: 134px; 
    height: 100px;
    background: #40174F;
    position: relative;
    color:white;
 } 
.octagon::before
 {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 top: 0; 
 left: 0; 
 border-bottom: 25px solid #40174F;
 border-left: 25px solid #fff; 
 border-right: 25px solid #fff;
 width: 84px; 
 height: 0; 
 color:white;

 } 
 .octagon::after
 {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0; border-top: 25px solid #40174F; border-left: 25px solid #fff; border-right: 25px solid #fff; width: 84px; height: 0; 
 color:white;
 }
```

The text inside the div is not showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add line-height and text-align in .octagon class

```
.octagon {
    width: 134px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #40174F;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    line-height: 6;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @tariq-javed. Really Helpful!